# How can I gen model class form yaml in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I was use Doctrine 1 generateModelsFromYaml

ex.
Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml($schemasPath, $modelsPath);

but , when I use Doctrine 2

how can I generate model classes form yaml ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doctrine 2 Console tool includes entity generation - outlined here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#entity-generation

Comment: your answer is right , but I also find a good exsample , http://thingswithpixels.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-doctrine-2-part-1